# What does => mean in python output and how can I get the right side value

Tags: python, python-gitlab

I am using python-gitlab (https://github.com/python-gitlab/python-gitlab)

And in my code I want to get values from project issues:

```
statistics = project.issuesstatistics.get()
print(statistics)
print(type(statistics))
```

The output is the following:

```
<class 'gitlab.v4.objects.ProjectIssuesStatistics'> => {'statistics': {'counts': {'all': 1, 'closed': 0, 'opened': 1}}}
<class 'gitlab.v4.objects.ProjectIssuesStatistics'>
```

The right side is just a dict and I want to have the value for 'all'.
But how can I get the dict from the right side?
I need something like `statistics.values()`

Comment: That's presumably part of the `__repr__` for a `ProjectIssuesStatistics` object - did you read the docs for that object to understand what attributes it has?

Comment: Yes I read this:
https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gl_objects/projects.html#project-issues-statistics

But there is not much to read, just two examples.

And I also grepped through the code:
https://github.com/python-gitlab/python-gitlab/blob/master/gitlab/v4/objects/statistics.py

But I still don't know how to get the dict ;-)

Comment: Have you tried `dir(statistics)` to see the available attributes and methods?

Comment: No, I did not do that!
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

In python-gitlab V4 you can use `attributes` property to get the value of the right hand side of the arrow. Something like this:

`gl.issues.list[0].attirbutes`

Answer (score 0):

The arrow as such does not have any special meaning in this context; the designer of this particular class decided to use this formatting when you `print` the bare object.

(In some more detail, when you convert an object into a string, its `__str__` method is called, and should return a string. It could return whatever it wants, like `"42"` or `"=> => =>"`, though the usual expectation would be for it to return a string which reveals the actual value held by the object in some sort of vaguely human-readable representation.)

In the general case, you would consult the documentation for the library, or inspect what methods are available (the `dir()` function is helpful for this, and of course the `help()` function, which displays any documentation string).